# generate csv without footer Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to generate a csv file with pandas to incorporate it into GCS, however, when generating the dataframe, the csv is generated with a blank line at the end. How can I remove it?

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv(path, chunksize=chunk_size, names=columnas, sep= ';', low_memory=False, dtype=dtype):
                chunk.to_csv("gs://.csv", index=False, sep=';', header=False)
                contador +=1
```

Comment: do you really have problem with empty line at the end? I think more tools should simply skip this empty line when they read file and it shouldn't make any problem

Comment: Please provide a reproducible code that others can try. The code which you have provided now doesn't fully convey your question.

Comment: BTW: if you want to append data to existing file (ie. in for-loop) then you should use `append mode` - `.to_csv(..., mode="a")`